# Get all diffs related to a certain user in Subversion

Tags: svn

What is the easiest way to get all changes that was made by a certain user? By changes I mean diff between revision before and after his commit.

Comment: You may be interested in: [Extract relevant changes for code review](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/78339/extract-relevant-changes-for-code-review)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your user is, say, "spolsky":

```
  svn log | sed -n '/spolsky/,/-----$/ p'
```

Comment: As I understand, it will give me only revisions which I need to feed to svn diff

Comment: that is true. as far as I know there is no generic way to get a set of diffs from any one svn command.